# Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense is broken after ReSharper suspended (license expired) / uninstalled

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense is broken after ReSharper suspended (license expired) / uninstalled. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when ReSharper suspended or uninstalled, it fails to restore the original Visual Studio's IntelliSense.

What worked for me to restore IntelliSense is: Tools (Menu) | Import and Export Settings | Import and Export Settings Wizard | Reset all settings ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022)):

[image]

After the `Next >`, comes the `Choose a Default Collection of Settings` page. Select a collection (C++, C#, etc.) and then select `Finish` and `Close`.